# post data array with formData axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data

i will send array data using formData.
the backend accepts the data array with a dash ;
example if in postman using form-data like this:

```
id_barang : 122;288;383 (send 3 value id with dash ;)
```

if i use formData is it like this?

```
  data [
       {
          id_barang : 122
       },
       {
          id_barang : 288
       },
       {
          id_barang : 383
       }
    ]
    
     let barang = data.map(x => x.id_barang).join(";");
     const f = new FormData();
     f.append("id_barang", barang);


     //please correct me if i'm wrong
```

my backend

```
    id_barang_data := strings.Split(r.FormValue("id_barang"), ";") // => 1002;983;756
    
    for i, _ := range id_barang_data { // loop through the files one by one
            rSegAnalisaMethodDetail := models.SegAnalisaMethodDetail{}
            id_barang, err := strconv.Atoi(id_barang_data[i])
            if err != nil {
                responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusBadGateway, err)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. the only thing missing here is that you didn't provide a way of sending your request with axios. when you use `FormData` with axios you need to add `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`. however if you don't add any files to `Formdata` then there is no need to use `Formdata`

Here is the compete action:

```js
var banyakBarang = [
    { id_barang: 122 },
    { id_barang: 288 },
    { id_barang: 383 }
];

var barangString = banyakBarang.map(function(barang) {
    return barang.id_barang;
}).join(';');

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id_barang', barangString);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/x',
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
});
```

Request Payload:

```
id_barang: 122;288;383
```

Comment: I have used this, sir, but when I post, the data on the backend is not looped or only 1 is entered..
if you use postman the data works everything

Comment: You need to `split (js) / explode (php)` the value. Show your code how you handle it on the backend.

Comment: I've updated my question with backend code content :D

Comment: I tracked the backend again, it seems there is another form that is not looped causing the 'id_barang' loping to fail, thank you for the answer kang ,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify your array and append it in the FormData and in the backend, you can parse that data and use it accordingly. Check out the example below.

```js
let formData = new FormData();

let data = [
       {
          id_barang : 122
       },
       {
          id_barang : 288
       },
       {
          id_barang : 383
       }
    ]
formData.append("arr", JSON.stringify(data));


for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios has paramsSerializer option, you can set it to comma-separated arrayFormat with qs.stringify.

```
const paramsSerializer = (params: any) => stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'comma' });
```